# Python GUI tkinter - solve secondary loop

Tags: python, loops, user-interface, tkinter

I m beginner in Python. Exist any possible way, how to loop in def and return to mainloop after user make some reaction, like click button?
In code down: Mainloop jump to def work, next to def start. After click button Start change the Buttons and after click on it, return to mainloop. So command "print ("App comes here...")" execute after clicking new button...
Thx a lot for any clue.

```
from tkinter import *


win_dow=Tk()
win_dow.geometry("600x300")



def work():
    def start():
        "Here somehow loop"
        line_2_r2.remove(btn_start)
        line_2_r2.add(btn_back)

    def back():
        """
        Here return to mainloop...
        """
        line_2_r2.remove(btn_back)
        line_2_r2.add(btn_start)
        
    
    pan_win = PanedWindow(win_dow, borderwidth = 0, bg = "black", width = 600, height = 300, orient=VERTICAL)
    pan_win.pack()
    line_1 = PanedWindow(pan_win, borderwidth = 0, bg = "blue", width = 600, height = 100, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    pan_win.add(line_1)
    line_2 = PanedWindow(pan_win, borderwidth = 0, bg = "black", width = 600, height = 100, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    pan_win.add(line_2)
    line_2_r1 = PanedWindow(line_2, borderwidth = 0, bg = "yellow", width = 200, height = 100, orient=VERTICAL)
    line_2.add(line_2_r1)
    line_2_r2 = PanedWindow(line_2, borderwidth = 0, bg = "orange", width = 200, height = 100, orient=VERTICAL)
    line_2.add(line_2_r2)
    line_2_r3 = PanedWindow(line_2, borderwidth = 0, bg = "purple", width = 200, height = 100, orient=VERTICAL)
    line_2.add(line_2_r3)
    line_3 = PanedWindow(pan_win, borderwidth = 0, bg = "green", width = 600, height = 100, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    pan_win.add(line_3)
    btn_start = Button(line_2_r2, text= "Start", font="Arial, 12", command=start)
    line_2_r2.add(btn_start)
    btn_back = Button(line_2_r2, text= "Go back", font="Arial, 12", command=back)

work()
print ("App comes here...")

win_dow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you explain your requirement in a clearer manner, perhaps as an ordered list of steps?

Comment: you are trying to call a function `start()` from within another function `work()`. So, even though this is valid in python, the inner function might not be in the same scope...

Comment: If you want to print "App comes here" after each time you press the start button then just add it in the start function... Like `def start(): `
`print("App comes here...")`
`line_2_r2.remove(btn_start)`
`line_2_r2.add(btn_back)`

Comment: Problem is not to move print command into function (It is there just for knowing, that program jumped back to mainloop after function...).  What i want to solve is, that program is runing mainloop step by step, from mainloop jump to function and i need to program cycle in this function, before it jumps back to next step in mainloop. Like make "mainloop" inside the function. And not using standard cycle, but stop the cycling in this function by using button, or some reaction from user.